# Cannot get promise results with promise.all()

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js, bulkupdate

I have mutiple update promises with sequelize and execute them parallely by Promise.all

All I get as Result is this: [[1]]

Here is the Code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const PLZ = require('../models/index').PLZ;
const Zone = require('../models/index').Zone;
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

router.post('/add', function (req, res, next) {
    let zone = {
        name: req.body.name,
        color: req.body.color
    };

    const plzs = req.body.plzs;

    for (let i = 0; i < plzs.length; i++) {
        if (plzs[i].plz.toString() === plzs[i].city && plzs[i].plz.toString() === plzs[i].district) {
            plzs[i].city = null;
            plzs[i].district = null;
        }
        delete plzs[i].checked;
    }

    Zone.create(zone).then((result_zone) => {
        let update_operations = [];
        let zone_plzs = [];

        // associate with plzs and put PLZs to database
        for (let i = 0; i < plzs.length; i++) {
            plzs[i].zone_id = result_zone.dataValues.id;
            zone_plzs.push(plzs[i]);

            update_operations.push(PLZ.update({zone_id: plzs[i].zone_id}, {where: {id: plzs[i].id}}).then((result) => {
                return result
            }));
        }

        Promise.all(update_operations)/*.then((arrayOfArrays) => {
            return [].concat.apply([], arrayOfArrays);
        })*/.then((result) => {
            res.send({status: true, data: {zone: result_zone, plzs: result}})
        }).catch(function (err) {
            return next(err);
        });

    }).catch(function (err) {
        next(err)
    });
});
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

**Edit: I inserted the whole route to give you more details.**

Comment: You are pushing a promise, with a `then` clause into an array, for your `Promise.all`. Your promise is already being handled before you get to the `Promise.all`

Comment: I edited the first post and inserted the whole route code and the imports.

Comment: @EvanBechtol there is nothing wrong about putting an array of promises with `then` clauses into `Promise.all`, as long as you return something in the said `then` clauses

Comment: it's redundant in the OP's case, yes, but not harmful in any way. The OP just re-returns the results

Comment: this is not working as @shkaper said, there is no effect.

Comment: Start removing code that isn't relevant to your problem. Start by ensuring your DB queries, each and every one of them, give you the result you expect.

Comment: The code is actually working as expected. I tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update function of sequelize returns a number of affected rows (first parameter of result array).**

```
PLZ.update({zone_id: plzs[i].zone_id}, {where: {id: plzs[i].id}}).then((result) => {
    return result
});
```

So the **output** of this will be **`[1]`** , and then you push this into **`update_operations`** , for Promise.All

Promise.All will return the array of results so `[[1]]` , this is what you will get. So there is nothing wrong in that , you are getting what is right.

---

I think , what you want is returning the result , instead of affected rows , in that case you need to add `returning: true` , like

```
PLZ.update(
    {   zone_id: plzs[i].zone_id    }, 
    {   
        where: {id: plzs[i].id} ,
        returning: true, // <--------- HERE
    }
);
```

> NOTE : There is no need of .then((result) => { return result }); in
>   your code . it will work without that also

Comment: Thanks I found out, its true what you said. But what to do, if I want to have the real result?

Comment: I have also mentioned that in answer , please read the last portion